# Setting a variable outside of an instance method does not work

Tags: java, oop

I am able to do this and i found no error on this code while accessing the class properties.

```java
public class Bike {
    String name;
    private String color;
    int speedometer = 78;
    String numberPlate;
}
```

but, if write the code like below, I am getting an error, when i try to access it another class of same package.

```java
public class Bike {
    String name;
    private String color;
    int speedometer;
    speedometer = 78;
    String numberPlate;
}
```

Comment: `speedometer = 78;` you can't do this outside of an instance method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Or a constructor. Or an initializer block.

Comment: When you make the assignment inside the declaration, it's an initialization rather than a statement. When you separate them, the assignment is a statement, and needs to be inside a method, a constructor or an initializer block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why am i not able to do this?

The short answer is: because it is not valid Java.

At the top level of a Java class, the only things that can appear are declarations and initializer blocks.

- Declarations comprise *field declarations*, *constructor declarations*, *method declarations* and (nested) *type declarations* of various kinds.
- Initializer blocks comprise *static initializer blocks* and *instance initializer blocks*.  (Initializer blocks are rarely seen, so you may not have encountered them yet.)

In your "good" example, each one of the lines within the class is a field declaration.  This one:

```
int speedometer = 78;
```

is a field declaration *with an initializer*.

In your "bad" example:

```
int speedometer;
speedometer = 78;
```

are two separate constructs.  The first is a field declaration (without an initializer).  That is allowed.  The second is an *assignment statement*.  An assignment statement is NOT a declaration, and therefore is not allowed at this point in a Java class.

Statements (in general) are allowed within the body of a method, constructor or a lambda, or within an initializer block.